# Opencart Images not displaying

Tags: php, opencart

Ok so i moved hosting. Everything is working great except i cant get images to show up on the site. The only place that they show up is when you are editing the product on the image tab. No images are displayed on the list of products nor on the front end.

I have no idea what is going on here. If it helps at all when i inspect elements on the list of products page the "src" is blank but has alt text. But on the front end there is just nothing, no image tag at all.

I am not really sure where to start on this one. I have tried changing the path on the

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', BASE_DIR.'/image/');
```

To the absolute path on the server to the image directory, but that didn't help.

I have tried a few things that i found on google like deleting the cache directory.

Any ideas on something anything to try to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make sure all of your details are correct is to do a "fresh install" to generate the configuration files again. Here's what you need to do

1. Back up your `config.php` and `admin/config.php` files to `config.backup.php`
2. Create a new database to use (this ensures that your original remains and can be used once your configs are created)
3. Clear the contents of your original `config.php` files and make sure they are writeable
4. Go to `http://yoursite.com/install` and fill in the details for the site, including the new database details *NOT THE ORIGINALS*
5. Once install is completed, Open the `config.php` and `admin/config.php` and change the database details at the bottom to match those of the originals in `config.backup.php`
6. Delete the new database and remove the `config.backup.php` files if everything has successfully been restored

Answer (score 0):

If it were me and you would like your site not to go down. I would simply do a search on the code base for your old domain, and more importantly do a search in mysql for instances of your old domain.

Searching your codebase is easy using grep on command line. If you are not comfortable with command line download Sublime Text editor, download your code base and use Sublime to very quickly search the entire codebase.

Use phpmyadmin to search your database and use this snippet to replace your old domain with the new one: http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/find-replace.html

Hope that helps

I would like to point out you should always back up your website before doing this sort of change (that includes your database), and always test on a development instance where available!